# Webpage not loading fully in Webview in Android API 24 but does in others

Tags: android, android-emulator, html

I'm showing a local webpage into a WebView in my app.

So far I've tested it on physical devices with API 23 and API 19 and in emulated device with API 22 and the web page has displayed properly.

But now I'm emulating a device in API 24 and what's shown is only about half of the webpage, indeed an image of it is cut and from that point nothing else is shown.

My guess is that it has to be some type of emulator bug for this version, as it doesn't make much of a sense that it is able to load the web page fully in older API versions, especially considering that one of them has also been done in an emulator, but not in this one, but... who knows.

Code doesn't give any error, it looks like when it's told to load the web page it loads up to that point and no more.

Has someone suffered a similar problem? If so, how was it solved?

Comment: You can show screen capture of emulator?

Comment: I guess my company wouldn't be very happy about that... but thanks for your interest.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You try to add some settings:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://www.yourlink.com/");
```

In manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```